# JQuery wrap() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't the following code wrap the image with `<li>` tags and what would be the best way to do this?

```
var i = new Image
i.src = '/images/image.jpeg'

$(i).wrap('<li />')
$('div').html(i)
```

produces:

```
<div><img src="/images/image.jpeg"></div>
```

instead desired:

```
<div><li><img src="/images/image.jpeg"></li></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you wouldn't just do this?

```
$('div').html('<li><img src="/images/image.jpeg" /></li>');
```

Please note that either way you are appending an `<li>` element to a `<div>` which is not technically correct.

The `<li>` should be a child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

---

**EDIT:**

Specific to the issue you were having, your code was correct, but you just needed to place the wrapped `<img>` inside the `.html()` call:

```
var i = new Image;
i.src = '/images/image.jpeg';

$('div').html( $(i).wrap('<li />') );
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a reference to the image. `wrap` doesn't change that. Can't you just generate the `li` then appendTo on the li?

```
i = new Image;
$('<li/>').append(i).appendTo('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` overwrites all the content what's inside the element. So it removes that `<li>` over there.

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = '/images/image.jpeg';

var li = $(i).wrap($('<li/>')).parent();   // since .wrap returns the inner element
$('<div/>').html(li)
```

then you get the proper structure:

[image]